# NPM в WSL ошибка путей

Tags: node.js, npm, path, wsl2

Имеется проблема:

- когда я пытаюсь выполнить скрипт `npm run`, внутри `WSL` директории при помощи `Windows-версии Node/NPM`, появляются данные ошибки:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Их причина заключается, скорее всего, в проблеме распознавания пути `\\wsl.localhost\`, из-за чего `npm` не может найти модули по заданному пути. Если переместить все эти модули в отдельную виндовскую папку и запустить `npm run dev` там, то все работает как часы. Если запускать `npm run dev` внутри папки, которая находится в `WSL`, то появляются такие ошибки. Как можно этого избежать?

`NPM` для `WSL (Ubuntu)` вовсе отказывается билдить эти модули по неизвестной мне причине (прогресс просто останавливается на 0% без ошибок), поэтому пришлось использовать виндовс вариацию `NPM`.

Comment: [Симлинк](https://winitpro.ru/index.php/2021/03/03/ispolzovanie-simlink-ssylok-v-windows/) ?

Comment: Куда нужно симлинк повесить?

Comment: У вас в нпм не работает путь вида ```\\wsl.localhost\...\...```, что вам мешает сделать симлинк вида ```c:/MyFolder``` ведущий на  ```\\wsl.localhost\...\...```, если проблема с UNC путями а не чем либо еще - это поможет.

Comment: Я бы остановился на том, чтобы всё (и проект, и node.js с npm) были в WSL. Хорошо бы узнать что в package.json и корректно ли устанавливаются все пакеты до запуска